# Copying one python list to another using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to copy one list to another using python multiprocessing module, but target list remains unchanged. Code below

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def copy_func(i,list2,list1):
    list2[i]=list1[i]
processes = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    process = mp.Process(target=copy_func, args=(i,list2,list1))
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

A spawned process will have a *copy* of the memory state of the initial process. Changes made in the new process won't be reflected automatically in the parent, you need to do that explicitly either via [exchanging objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) using a `Pipe` or `Queue`, or by passing a [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) data structure. Read the linked docs for examples.